# Dont know how to join shapes

Tags: mesh

I started with a single block with an image template and ended up at a point where two edges looped around and came into contact with each other. I do not know how to connect them so I ended up extruding a shape from where the arrow is in the image then aligning its edges with the shapes on either side of it, it looked fine so I went to do a subdivision surface and it ended up with this wonky shape sitting between the sides it is supposed to connect to as seen in the other image. Now i have no idea on how to fix this or if there is a way I am still a bit new to using blender and could really use the help.[image] [image]

Comment: Try going to edit mode, select all, then `mesh > clean up > merge by distance`. You may have to reduce the distance threshold in the box that pops up in the bottom left corner. Decrease the distance until it merges the two sides if necessary.

Comment: oh my god thank you